Java TestContainers run with rootless Podman inside a non privileged Container
I want to run a a java TestContainer inside a non privileged container with a rootless podman. My docker commande to start it is like :
$: docker run --security-opt seccomp=unconfined --security-opt label=disable --device /dev/fuse -it --rm --user podman my-podman:latest

The test is very simple :
@SpringBootTest
class AnyTest {

    static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer<>(
            "postgres:16-alpine"
    );

    @BeforeAll
    static void beforeAll() {
        postgres.start();
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void afterAll() {
        postgres.stop();
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}

And the my-image Dockerfile:
FROM quay.io/podman/stable

RUN yum install -y java-17-openjdk-devel
ENV JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/jre_17
ENV GRADLE_USER_HOME="/home/podman/.gradle"

RUN mkdir ${GRADLE_USER_HOME} \
    && chmod -R 755 ${GRADLE_USER_HOME}

COPY . /app

RUN rm -rf /app/.gradle
RUN mkdir -p /app/.gradle
RUN chmod -R 777 /app

ENV TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED=true

When I start the container I cannot run podman as a service:
$: systemctl --user enable --now podman.socket


Created symlink
/home/podman/.config/systemd/user/sockets.target.wants/podman.socket →
/usr/lib/systemd/user/podman.socket.
Failed to connect to bus: No medium found

$:podman --remote info shows me this message:
OS: linux/arm64
provider: qemu
version: 5.2.3

Cannot connect to Podman. Please verify your connection to the Linux system using `podman system connection list`, or try `podman machine init` and `podman machine start` to manage a new Linux VM
Error: unable to connect to Podman socket: Get "http://d/v5.2.3/libpod/_ping": dial unix /tmp/storage-run-1000/podman/podman.sock: connect: no such file or directory: unix:///tmp/storage-run-1000/podman/podman.sock

Cannot doing this I've tryied the other way as described here :
$: podman system service --time=0 unix:///tmp/podman.sock &
$: export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///tmp/podman.sock

This way TestContainers finds podman but it cannot starts the container !
But when running manually the same image it starts correcty :
$: podman run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=any -it --rm postgres:16-alpine


...
...
PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

2024-10-11 07:21:27.669 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.4 on aarch64-unknown-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 13.2.1_git20240309) 13.2.1 20240309, 64-bit
2024-10-11 07:21:27.669 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2024-10-11 07:21:27.669 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2024-10-11 07:21:27.670 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2024-10-11 07:21:27.673 UTC [50] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-10-11 07:21:27 UTC
2024-10-11 07:21:27.675 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections

$: podman info shows the following
host:
  arch: arm64
  buildahVersion: 1.37.3
  cgroupControllers:
  - cpuset
  - cpu
  - io
  - memory
  - hugetlb
  - pids
  - rdma
  cgroupManager: cgroupfs
  cgroupVersion: v2
  conmon:
    package: conmon-2.1.12-2.fc40.aarch64
    path: /usr/bin/conmon
    version: 'conmon version 2.1.12, commit: '
  cpuUtilization:
    idlePercent: 99.28
    systemPercent: 0.27
    userPercent: 0.45
  cpus: 12
  databaseBackend: sqlite
  distribution:
    distribution: fedora
    variant: container
    version: "40"
  eventLogger: file
  freeLocks: 2048
  hostname: 2448b4667c3c
  idMappings:
    gidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 1000
      size: 1
    - container_id: 1
      host_id: 1
      size: 999
    - container_id: 1000
      host_id: 1001
      size: 64535
    uidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 1000
      size: 1
    - container_id: 1
      host_id: 1
      size: 999
    - container_id: 1000
      host_id: 1001
      size: 64535
  kernel: 6.4.16-linuxkit
  linkmode: dynamic
  logDriver: k8s-file
  memFree: 920879104
  memTotal: 4116799488
  networkBackend: netavark
  networkBackendInfo:
    backend: netavark
    dns:
      package: aardvark-dns-1.12.2-2.fc40.aarch64
      path: /usr/libexec/podman/aardvark-dns
      version: aardvark-dns 1.12.2
    package: netavark-1.12.2-1.fc40.aarch64
    path: /usr/libexec/podman/netavark
    version: netavark 1.12.2
  ociRuntime:
    name: crun
    package: crun-1.17-1.fc40.aarch64
    path: /usr/bin/crun
    version: |-
      crun version 1.17
      commit: 000fa0d4eeed8938301f3bcf8206405315bc1017
      rundir: /tmp/storage-run-1000/crun
      spec: 1.0.0
      +SYSTEMD +SELINUX +APPARMOR +CAP +SECCOMP +EBPF +CRIU +LIBKRUN +WASM:wasmedge +YAJL
  os: linux
  pasta:
    executable: /usr/bin/pasta
    package: passt-0^20240906.g6b38f07-1.fc40.aarch64
    version: |
      pasta 0^20240906.g6b38f07-1.fc40.aarch64-pasta
      Copyright Red Hat
      GNU General Public License, version 2 or later
        <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html>
      This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
      There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
  remoteSocket:
    exists: false
    path: /tmp/storage-run-1000/podman/podman.sock
  rootlessNetworkCmd: pasta
  security:
    apparmorEnabled: false
    capabilities: CAP_CHOWN,CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE,CAP_FOWNER,CAP_FSETID,CAP_KILL,CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE,CAP_SETFCAP,CAP_SETGID,CAP_SETPCAP,CAP_SETUID,CAP_SYS_CHROOT
    rootless: true
    seccompEnabled: true
    seccompProfilePath: /usr/share/containers/seccomp.json
    selinuxEnabled: false
  serviceIsRemote: false
  slirp4netns:
    executable: ""
    package: ""
    version: ""
  swapFree: 88252416
  swapTotal: 1073737728
  uptime: 51h 45m 14.00s (Approximately 2.12 days)
  variant: v8
plugins:
  authorization: null
  log:
  - k8s-file
  - none
  - passthrough
  - journald
  network:
  - bridge
  - macvlan
  - ipvlan
  volume:
  - local
registries:
  search:
  - registry.fedoraproject.org
  - registry.access.redhat.com
  - docker.io
store:
  configFile: /home/podman/.config/containers/storage.conf
  containerStore:
    number: 0
    paused: 0
    running: 0
    stopped: 0
  graphDriverName: overlay
  graphOptions: {}
  graphRoot: /home/podman/.local/share/containers/storage
  graphRootAllocated: 251647299584
  graphRootUsed: 66340667392
  graphStatus:
    Backing Filesystem: extfs
    Native Overlay Diff: "true"
    Supports d_type: "true"
    Supports shifting: "false"
    Supports volatile: "true"
    Using metacopy: "false"
  imageCopyTmpDir: /var/tmp
  imageStore:
    number: 1
  runRoot: /tmp/storage-run-1000/containers
  transientStore: false
  volumePath: /home/podman/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes
version:
  APIVersion: 5.2.3
  Built: 1727136000
  BuiltTime: Tue Sep 24 02:00:00 2024
  GitCommit: ""
  GoVersion: go1.22.7
  Os: linux
  OsArch: linux/arm64
  Version: 5.2.3

I can run : podman machine init --log-level=DEBUG inside the container but it fails at the end :
DEBU[0002] Compression change for blob sha256:96367a6aac795136ea8cf1d0ed4fecef39ad7d15dd3de38f22710abc7a8bb1a2 ("application/zstd") not supported 
Copying blob 96367a6aac79 done   | 
DEBU[0027] Downloading /v2/podman/machine-os/blobs/sha256:44136fa355b3678a1146ad16f7e8649e94fb4fc21fe77e8310c060f61caaff8a 
DEBU[0027] GET https://quay.io/v2/podman/machine-os/blobs/sha256:44136fa355b3678a1146ad16f7e8649e94fb4fc21fe77e8310c060f61caaff8a 
Copying config 44136fa355 [--------------------------------------] 0.0b / 2.0b | 0.0 b/s
DEBU[0028] No compression detected                      
DEBU[0028] Compression change for blob sha256:44136fa355b3678a1146ad16f7e8649e94fb4fc21fe77e8310c060f61caaff8a ("application/vnd.oci.empty.v1+json") not supported 
Copying config 44136fa355 done   | 
Writing manifest to image destination
DEBU[0028] socket length for /home/podman/.local/share/containers/podman/machine/qemu/cache/11ade9185bb322ae12a6e1d08aa3929e82d73260dddc59def02916fe4ef35e28 is 127 
DEBU[0028] socket length for /home/podman/.local/share/containers/podman/machine/qemu/cache/11ade9185bb322ae12a6e1d08aa3929e82d73260dddc59def02916fe4ef35e28.qcow2.zst is 137 
96367a6aac795136ea8cf1d0ed4fecef39ad7d15dd3de38f22710abc7a8bb1a2
DEBU[0028] Detected compression format zstd             
Extracting compressed file: podman-machine-default-arm64.qcow2: done  
DEBU[0032] --> imagePath is "/home/podman/.local/share/containers/podman/machine/qemu/podman-machine-default-arm64.qcow2" 
DEBU[0032] socket length for /home/podman/.config/containers/podman/machine/qemu/podman-machine-default.ign is 78 
Error: exit status 1
DEBU[0032] Shutting down engines   

Here is a minimal reproduction code with all steps for running it

did you find a solution?

nope, I didn't :')
